# Does an 'if' statement always evaluate all conditions?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Objective-C use short-circuit evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060741/does-objective-c-use-short-circuit-evaluation)

If an object is of a certain type, and a property of that object has a certain value, I want to do something.

Can I use:

```
if (objectIsOfType:x && object.property == y)
```

or do I need to nest these? Assume that asking for object.property will through an error if the object is not of type x.

Comment: Thanks - I was missing the term to search for. Is it good practice for me to delete this?

Comment: I don't think so - see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Objective C (as C and many other languages) uses [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Comment: if `objectIsOfType:x` will fail, the whole `if` will be false, which is the intended behaviour. since he needs `objectOfType:x` to be type x when evaluating the `object.property` then it should work in the case supplied by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C supports short-circuit evaluation(from left to right).
but in any way, you need to check object on nil :))